# What's the reason for the O'Ren-Ishii animation sequence?

Tags: kill-bill, quentin-tarantino

Recently I've had the opportunity to watch Tarantino's *Kill Bill: Vol. 1*. It was lots of blood and gore. However, I liked the movie very much. The one which I liked most was, O'Ren-Ishii's lengthy Japanese-animated introduction scene. While watching this scene, I wonder, ***Why did Tarantino want to show O'Ren-Ishii's character as a animated sequence*** in particularly. How did he get that idea?

Does he explained the reason for this scene in any interview?

[**Here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImyntxVxZyE), I've embedded the video of that scene.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the information from this [site](http://www.ugo.com/movies/the-animated-history-of-o-ren-ishii-kill-bill-comic-con) which contains the interview given by the animation producer for that shot:

> One of the most striking sequences in both Kill Bill films is the
>   backstory sequence of Deadly Viper Assassination Squad member O-Ren
>   Ishii. Tarantino collaborated with Production I., the anime studio
>   behind Ghost in the Shell, Blood: The Last Vampire and segments of The
>   Animatrix, to craft this bloody, hand-drawn expansion of mythology, an
>   setup that dimensionalizes Ishii and her violent practices.
>
> Animation producer [Katsuji Morishita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katsuji_Morishita) explained to CGSociety that,
>   "Quentin himself came to our studios to meet with us in person. He
>   already had the image and style in mind, and wanted us to make the
>   animation based on his script. He actually acted out the performances
>   of the characters to be animated in front of us. There were 4
>   sequences in all, and the production period was 1 year. Those 4
>   sequences would've been extremely difficult to make in live-action.
>   Even if it had been possible, it would've taken tremendous amount of
>   budget and work."
>
> No kidding -- the price tag for the blood alone would have been seven
>   figures.

Comment: 1 year for 4 sequences. That itself is impressive that a director would allow that. I don't think there are many that would understand the work involved these days.

Answer (score 6):

Tarantino once said that he got [inspiration for this scene](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2012-07-16/news-interviews/32697700_1_kamal-haasan-aalavandhan-anurag-kashyap) from Tamil language film "Aalavandhan"(2001) starring Kamal Hassan.